# touch screen not working in hp 2760p but the wacom pen is working good

Tags: hp, touchscreen

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
My laptop is hp 2760p
The touch screen is not working
But the Wacom pen is working well
What should I do to make it work normally?!

here is the code when i type input --list

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer   (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Serial Penabled 2FG Touchscreen Pen stylus  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Serial Penabled 2FG Touchscreen Finger touch    id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Serial Penabled 2FG Touchscreen Pen eraser  id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ HP HD Webcam [Fixed]                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Could you please open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1), run the command `xinput --list` and select, copy and paste its output into your question (with the help of the [edit] link below it)? Use the `{}` button in the editor toolbar to format the listing as pre-formatted code to preserve the indentation and line breaks. Thanks.